# ip neighbor nud permanent IS NOT PERMANENT

Tags: linux, openwrt

After issuing the following command:

```
ip neighbor add 192.168.255.254 lladdr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev br-lan nud permanent
```

The following entry can be found in the ARP cache:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip neigh
...
192.168.255.254 dev br-lan lladdr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff PERMANENT
```

...and all is nice and dandy.  However, after several hours this entry becomes:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip neigh
...
192.168.255.254 dev br-lan  FAILED
```

I can temporarily repair it by issuing this command:

```
ip neighbor change 192.168.255.254 lladdr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev br-lan nud permanent
```

...and it remains correct for several hours, but after that, it reverts back to:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip neigh
...
192.168.255.254 dev br-lan  FAILED
```

**Q: How can I make this ARP cache entry really permanent ?**

*BTW: I need it to make WOL work, since I forward an external UDP port to 192.168.255.254 which then gets broadcasted over my lan*

This is all happening on:
 `Linux OpenWrt 4.14.151 #0 SMP Tue Nov 5 14:12:18 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`.
`OpenWrt 18.06.5 r7897-9d401013fc / LuCI openwrt-18.06 branch (git-19.309.48729-bc17ef6)`

Comment: Keep `ip monitor` redirected to some log file running. You'll see when it happens. For example if `br-lan` is ever brought down, the entries are deleted

Comment: Or more probably: if a bridge port is added or removed (VM? container?), same happens

Comment: What about the `nud noarp` option ?

Comment: I can't manage to reproduce the problem (using kernel 5.16.x) . That's why I was asking about `ip monitor` (better: `ip -ts monitor`): to know in what context (the events before and after this deletion) it happens and be able to reproduce it. It's possible this was a bug that was corrected in recent kernels. 4.14 is still LTS but quite old (and might even have gotten a fix since last year). There are other ways to do this, like directed broadcasts (requires kernel 4.19): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655077/debian-wake-on-lan-packet-forwarding/655229#655229