# Debian Wake on LAN Packet Forwarding?

Tags: debian, wake-on-lan

I have an untangle box (debian 10 underneath) that I am attempting to forward a WOL packet from a host in one subnet to a host in another subnet.

My initial solution to this was to use knockd, listen for a syn packet on one of its interfaces on one subnet, then execute a etherwake command on the other subnet to wake up the host. I would send the syn packet using netcat from a linux server in the first subnet, sending the packet to the gateway IP (the untangle box).

Problem is, the traffic destined for the FW itself are processed initially in on unaddressed vlan interface. Its a bit weird, the syn packet is only seen on unaddressed interface, then all other packets are seen on the actual addressed vlan interface. I have confirmed this with tcpdump.
It breaks my plan on using knockd, because knockd refuses to listen on interfaces without an IP address.

I can see the syn packet coming into the unaddressed interface with tcpdump, and knockd uses tcpdump under the hood. So is there a way to force knockd to listen on an unaddressed interface anyways?

If knockd is just completely out of the question, how would you implement a WOL packet forwarder on Debian 10?

Comment: To better know what could be available among multiple methods. Is this really a Debian or does it just looks like one? Eg: what's the kernel version? Are the kernel options the same as on a stock Debian (eg nftables etc)?  Are you able to change the kernel (eg to the buster-backports one) if needed? etc. Also it's difficult to understand what additional challenge this untangle layer can be with what it's doing to routing if you can't understand it yourself.

Comment: It is in fact Debian 10. 
Kernel: 4.19.0-11

Comment: No suffix like -amd64, -armhf or something else?

Comment: Heres the whole uname -a: Linux hostname 4.19.0-11-untangle-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.146-1+untangle1buster (2020-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
       As far as I have seen, it is just debian buster. All the untangle specifics are built on top of existing technologies. I have installed standard Debian packages on it already.

Comment: It's not a Debian kernel so it wouldn't be safe to upgrade it to a Debian backport version. Just means the easy port knock replacement (in addition to the WOL feature) can't be easily implemented with nftables (it still could be, but probably too awkward to give it in the answer). I'll check how to give a WOL answer anyway later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of waking an host is that to send it a packet, the network stack must know the MAC address of the NIC. Normally it's dynamically handled by [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). If the MAC entry has been evicted from the router's ARP table, when the host is asleep it can't answer the ARP query, thus the router can't get the MAC address needed to reach the sleeping host to send it the WOL Magic Packet™ even if [such packet includes 16 times this MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet) in its payload.

Here are two methods to overcome this relying only on the network stack (and companions like *iptables* or *tc*).

### Permanent ARP

Since there is control on the router, one can set a permanent ARP entry on the router for the sleeping host. That way the previous problem will never happen. The router can now send or forward easily a WOL Magic Packet™ without having to use any broadcast anywhere. With NAT to "port forward", a remote host can then use the [`wakeonlan`](https://manpages.debian.org/wakeonlan.1) command (rather than the `etherwake` command, because it can change the UDP port).

The sleeping host thus needs a static address (or one with a permanent DHCP lease). Let's say the WAN address on the router is 192.0.2.2 on *wan0*, the LAN side on the router is 192.168.1.1/24 on interface *lan0* and the sleeping host 192.168.1.101/24 on an interface with MAC address 12:34:56:78:9a:bc.

On the router:

```
ip neighbour replace 192.168.1.101 lladdr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc dev lan0 nud permanent
```

As it's unclear if the packet received by the NIC will be consumed or still correctly made available to the waking host, it's traditionally port 9 that has been chosen because that's the *discard service* in case it's "running" and either would be the same. Pick an other port than 9 if needed. This port on the sleeping host should be preferably unused and firewalled (packets dropped), or actually running the discard service. As one port maps to one target, if there are multiple WOL hosts, each should have a different port.

The issue of a first packet arriving elsewhere in OP's description is worked around by selecting all interfaces that aren't the *lan0* interface.

So still on the router, using *iptables*, do the DNAT and allow the redirected packet:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING ! -i lan0 -p udp --dport 9 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101
iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 192.168.1.101 -j ACCEPT
```

A remote host on Internet can now do this to wake the sleeping host:

```
wakeonlan -i 192.0.2.2 -p 9 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

System integration depends on the method used for network configuration. For example if it's configured with [`interfaces`](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5) and *ifupdown*,  the two `iptables` commands could be added as `pre-up` commands in the `iface lan0 ...` stanza (and deleted in a `down` command), and the `ip neighbour` as `up` command.

---

### Directed subnet broadcast ([since kernel 4.19](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5cbf777cfdf6e5a7b7149006e4881a255da78fdd))

Tools always have options to use broadcast packets which end up as broadcast Ethernet frames that will reach all hosts, including the target host.

This can be done when routing but there are more risks involved (including participating in [reflected attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Reflected_/_spoofed_attack)). Ponder security before using.

The directed subnet broadcast must be enabled globally *and* on the receiving WAN interface (not the target LAN interface). If there are possibly multiple WAN interfaces (OP describes packets arriving first on an interface, then an other), enable it on all involved.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.bc_forwarding=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wan0.bc_forwarding=1
```

Add NAT and FORWARD rules:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING ! -i lan0 -p udp --dport 9 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.255
iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 192.168.1.255 -j ACCEPT
```

And as an option to limit risks, finally convert the IPv4 Ethernet frame (ethertype 0x800) into the de facto ethertype 0x842 used for WOL using *tc*, so the result will be ignored by network stacks (but not by WOL NICs). One could have used a mark set by iptables, or here just consider IP destination and UDP destination port 9. Former method would have clashed with marks if used by Untangle, either method will clash anyway if Untangle uses *tc* for QoS.

```
tc qdisc add dev lan0 root handle 1: prio # simple classful qdisc used only to enable filters
tc filter add dev lan0 parent 1: protocol ip basic match '
    cmp (u32 at 16 layer network eq 0xc0a801ff) and
    cmp (u8 at 9 layer network eq 17) and
    cmp (u16 at 2 layer transport eq 9)
    ' action skbmod set etype 0x842
```

Above,

- u32 at 16 layer network eq 0xc0a801ff means IP address destination 192.168.1.255,
- u8 at 9 layer network eq 17 means UDP,
- u16 at 2 layer transport eq 9 means destination port 9.
- and the resulting action is to change the ethertype to 0x842

Likewise a remote host on Internet can now do this to wake the sleeping host:

```
wakeonlan -i 192.0.2.2 -p 9 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

but it will target the whole LAN each time, so keeping the same port and just changing the MAC address is good enough when there are multiple sleeping WOL hosts.

---

Other method to consider:

[`fwknopd`](https://manpages.debian.org/fwknop-server/fwknopd.8) installed on the server and [`fwknop`](https://manpages.debian.org/fwknop-client/fwknop.8) installed on the client implement an encrypted **single** packet authorization mechanism to trigger commands. It could be used to trigger running `wakeonlan`/`etherwake` on the router.

Comment: Awesome answer. Did not realize I could use wakeonlan to send a unicast packet. I ended up adding firewall rules to the gui to take the place of the iptables rules. Went and added the ip neigh static command to a custom file in if-up.d. Hopefully it persists between untangle system upgrades. WOL now working! (Btw integrated this with apache guacamole too)